# Under what circumstances would styles not work in a CSS file but will work in a page header?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

Pretty simplistic markup.  I want to add a box with rounded corners to my form.  So, I have this CSS markup:

```
#rcorners2 {
 width:800px;
 height:150px;
 background:lightGrey; 
 border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

It's "called" from this div:

```
<div id="rcorners2">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Blah</td>
            <td>Blah</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

My app has a CSS file, so I added that markup to it.  Nothing happens.  No markup, the form loads with a generic square table in it.

I move the markup to the header section of my page and it works fine.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"> -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<!--  <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   -->

<!--//**********************************
        // Comment Character Count
        //**********************************  -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
                function textCounter(field, countfield, maxlimit) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                                if (field.value.length > maxlimit)
                                        field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
                                else
                                        countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;

                        }, 0);
                }
         </script>

    <script>
            $(function () {
                    var icons = {
                            header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
                            activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
                    };
                    $("#accordion").accordion({
                            icons: icons,
            collapsible: true
        });
    } );
    </script>

<style>
        #rcorners2 {
                width:800px;
                height:150px;
                background:lightGrey; 
                border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
                border: 2px solid black;
                overflow:hidden;
        }
</style>

</asp:Content>
```

Any idea why it's working in one spot and not the other?  This is a multi-page C#/ASP.net app running on IE9 (although I eventually need to get it running on IE11, Chrome and Firefox too, but that's for later).

Comment: You might need to reload the page to tell the browser not to used the cached CSS file....

Comment: Shouldn't the css files be always included in the header anyway?

Comment: Is it working in other browsers?

Comment: Well, I have a completely separate CSS file that is where I store all my markup.  My question is; why won't this markup work if it's just in this separate CSS file?  Instead, I have to put it in the page's header for it to work.  I'd rather keep it all in the CSS file.

Comment: It is usually a good idea to press `ctrl` + `F5` together after editing external CSS or JS files. This will force the browser to download the files again instead of reading them from cache.

Comment: @VDWWD - ctrl + F5 for the win!!  Can you put that as an answer?  I can give you the +25 if you do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually a good idea to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> together after editing external CSS or JS files. This will force the browser to download the files again instead of reading them from cache.

Comment: Perfect, this fixed my problem!